# How to correctly display a <string, object> pair

Tags: c#, idictionary

So, I was running through a C# online course in a class introducing IDictionary where they did this (for testing pairs that contain a string and an instance of a class):

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        IDictionary<string, Student> Students = new Dictionary<string, Student>();

        Students.Add("Ex1", new Student("Example 1", 34672 ));
        Students.Add("Ex2", new Student("Example 2", 8787));

        foreach (var item in Students)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public class Student
    {
        public string v1 { get; set; }
        public int v2 { get; set; }

        public Student (string v1, int v2)
        {
            this.v1 = v1;
            this.v2 = v2;
        }

    }
```

It's supposed to display the contents of the pair

```
[Ex1, {Example 1, 34672}]
```

but instead, it shows me:

```
[Ex1, ConsoleApp1.Program+Student]
```

This is a straight copy from the video, so I thought this could be some differences in the version of the .NET framework, but no. Just headed over SO to see if I'm not getting crazy. I could get the values using item.Value.v1, but that would require too much work on real-life instances, since I will have to run over all Values inside that object.

Comment: You could override `.ToString()` in the `Student` class.  Otherwise the default string representation of an object is its class name.

Comment: Thanks, David. I knew something was not adding up. The instructor was compiling and getting the correct display without any overrides. Wish I could mark  your comment as answer, since you're the first one to provide this solution (which works).

Comment: Sebastian's answer should be marked as the answer, as he was the first one to respond with an answer, rather than a comment. Pretty self-explanatory system really.

Comment: Yeah. I know how the system works, but nonetheless.. David DID provide the answer 2 minutes before Sebastian. He just didn't post any code. I was just thanking him for being the first one. I could just pick yours or Rawita's by the way, since you all didn't provide just the code, but the reason behind it.So, thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the ToString() Method in the Student class

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return "{" + v1 + "," + v2 + "}";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Within your `Student` class, you need to add an override for the `ToString()` method, as it is currently returning base.ToString(), which is the object's name itself, rather than the objects held within it (`string v1` and `int v2`).

Add this within your `Student` class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
     return "{" + v1 + "," + v2.ToString() + "}";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, object.ToString() will return type.
If you want something different you could override `ToString()` method

This is the implementation of `ToString()` in `object` class;

```
public virtual String ToString()
{
    return GetType().ToString();
}
```

So change your code to

```
public class Student
{
    public string v1 { get; set; }
    public int v2 { get; set; }
    public Student(string v1, int v2)
    {
        this.v1 = v1;
        this.v2 = v2;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{{{v1}, {v2}}}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try displaying item.key and item.value separately

Comment: There is no `key` nor `value` property in his `Student` class, but `v1` and `v2`